# Is it possible to show reminders only when I'm on a certain location?

Tags: ios, reminders, geolocation

I have some reminders every work day, but it only makes sense in office. Ever since COVID, I'm having more and more time working from home, and these reminders still pop up. Do we have anyway on iOS to show reminders only if I'm located in certain places?

Note: I'm not asking to be reminded when I arrive at my office. I only want to reminded, say, 13:00 every day if I'm in office at that time point. Third party apps are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution with the builtin Shortcuts App.

- Open Shortcuts
- Add a personal automation

  - The trigger is based on time
  - Add a location of the work
  - Add the computation of distance between the "current location" and the previous location
  - Add a conditional execution

    - The condition is the distance is less than some km
    - The execution is to show a reminder